# CCEventListener.cpp - Assertion failed when trying to implement touch functionality

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm fiddling around with Cocos2D-X and trying to implement touch functionality as per [this wiki entry](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/EventDispatcher_Mechanism). However, when I try to run my code, it launches and pops up a dialog saying "Assertion failed!" giving a reason "CCEventListenerTouch.cpp, Line:89, Expression: false".

Here's my code related to this:

```
bool MainLayer::init()
{
    Sprite* tile = Sprite::create("tile.png");
    this->addChild(tile);
    auto listener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
    listener->setSwallowTouches(true);

    listener->onTouchMoved = [](Touch* touch, Event* event)
    {
        tile->setPosition(tile->getPosition() + touch->getDelta());
    };

    _eventDispatcher->addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(listener, tile);

    return true;
}
```

If I uncomment the line before the `return`statement, it works without crashing, but the touches are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you actually have to implement all the onTouch* callbacks. I added these two and it started working.

```
listener->onTouchBegan = [&](Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    return true;
};

listener->onTouchEnded = [=](Touch* touch, Event* event)
{

};
```

Comment: Yes and it is also common to check to make sure your sprite contains the touch location, just to be sure.